# WMI query in C# does not work on NON-English Machine

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wmi-query, managementeventwatcher

I am creating an application that needs to track when a process starts, then raise an event when it's finished.

I have code that works perfectly, and does exactly what I need on an English machine, but when I run the same application on a French language machine it fails.

here's the code that fails

```
qstart = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent",
            new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5),
            "TargetInstance isa \"Win32_Process\"");

qstop = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceDeletionEvent",
            new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5),
            "TargetInstance isa \"Win32_Process\"");
        try
        {
            using (wstart = new ManagementEventWatcher(qstart))
            {
                wstart.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(ProcessStarted);
                Log.DebugEntry("BeginProcess() - Starting wstart Event");
                wstart.Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.DebugEntry("error on wstart: " + ex.Message);
        }

        using (wstop = new ManagementEventWatcher(qstop))
        {
            wstop.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(ProcessStopped);
            Log.DebugEntry("BeginProcess() - Starting wstop Event");
            wstop.Start();
        }
```

the error hits when it tries to start the query:
    wstart.Start();

and does the same for 
    wstop.Start();

I can only guess it has something to do with the language and the query string, but I'm clutching at straws.

The error it comes up with is:
**"demande non analysable"**

Any help is gratefully recieved!

Martyn

Edit: Tested on 2 identical Machines, only difference being the language chosen on first startup.

Comment: Are you sure it's locale that is the only difference? What about operating system version and Service Pack? As far as I know, locale won't impact if a query could be parsed (The English error is "Unparsable query").

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, But both machines have the same .net 3.5 and are both out of the box new. They are also both running windows 7 starter. I'll see if I can find another machine that I can start in a different language to test.

Comment: I have 2 of the same laptop and have tested this on one started with english. So definitly something to do with the language the machine is started with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently its because the interval you specified is too small... I just tried it on a French Windows XP SP3, and got the same error. But if I change the interval to 1 second instead, it works fine... It seems you can't specify an interval smaller than 1 second. Not sure why this only happens on a non-English OS, though...

EDIT: actually I just realized it's probably a bug in `WqlEventQuery`. The `qstart.QueryString` looks like that with CurrentCulture = "en-US" :

```
select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 0.005 where TargetInstance isa "Win32_Process"
```

But with CurrentCulture = "fr-FR" it looks like that:

```
select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 0,005 where TargetInstance isa "Win32_Process"
```

(note the difference in the number format)

So apparently the code in `WqlEventQuery` doesn't force the use of the invariant culture to format the number, making the query incorrect in cultures where the decimal separator is not "."

If you force the `CurrentCulture` to `CultureInfo.Invariant`, the query works fine, even on a French OS. You can also write the WQL query manually...

Comment: Wow, Thats annoying! I have to admit it hadn't crossed my mind that it would be affected by that, as it's been working perfectly fine on english! Well, you're answer is correct, I changed it to 1 second and it works. Massive thanks

Comment: @SmithSmart: actually it seems to be a culture-related bug in WqlEventQuery, see my updated answer

Comment: Awesome, I'd accept your answer twice if I could, being able to check in less than a second helps as I check the start process then all child processes. Great information.

Comment: Why don't you raise a bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/ so that it can be fixed in the framework.

Comment: @Pratik, I did, but I had to leave so I didn't post the link at once... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/667894/wqleventquery-doesnt-format-the-interval-correctly-in-some-non-english-cultures-leading-to-unparsablequery-error